# HTML `dialog` element: scroll content independently of background

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I am trying to use the `dialog` element.

When the dialog/modal is closed, the body should be scrollable.

When the dialog/modal is open, if it has large contents, the dialog/modal should be scrollable.

However, when the dialog/modal is open, I don't want scroll to apply to both the dialog/modal *and* the body background, which is what it seems to do by default.

Example: https://output.jsbin.com/mutudop/3.

How can I make scroll apply only to the dialog/modal contents, when the dialog/modal is open?

Note: I am only interested in solutions using the native `dialog` element.

Comment: Hey, I think some feedback would be nice. As far as I can see it you haven't responded to 2 answers so far. They need to know if their answers solve your question or if the answer/your question is/isn't relevant (anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried it as well and came up with this:

```js
(function() {
  var openBtn = document.querySelector("button#open");
  var myDialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

  openBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (typeof myDialog.showModal === "function") {
      myDialog.showModal();
      document.querySelector("body").classList.add("overflow-hidden");
    } else {
      alert("Dialog API not supported by browser");
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 10000px;
}

dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: transparent;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

dialog>div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <dialog>
    <div>
      <form method="dialog">
        <button onclick='document.body.classList.remove("overflow-hidden");' value="cancel">Cancel</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </dialog>

  <button id="open">Open Dialog</button>
  <h4>You can scroll the body now but not when the dialog is opened.</h4>
</div>
```

You might have noticed that I added two lines of JS to hide/show the `overflow` of the `body` and you will probably need them as you can't target the `body` with pure CSS if you want to check if the `dialog` is opened or not.

If you **don't** want them you **can** remove them and it just works fine. However, you will have two scroll bars on the right side. This is how it looks without the JS:

```js
(function() {
  var openBtn = document.querySelector("button#open");
  var myDialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

  openBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (typeof myDialog.showModal === "function") {
      myDialog.showModal();
    } else {
      alert("Dialog API not supported by browser");
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 10000px;
}

dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: transparent;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

dialog>div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <dialog>
    <div>
      <form method="dialog">
        <button value="cancel">Cancel</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </dialog>

  <button id="open">Open Dialog</button>
</div>
```

If you need any explanation let me know but I believe the code should be self-explanatory.

Comment: This answer doesn't take the escape key into account. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 5):

## 2023/2024 Solution (No Javascript / CSS Only)

It is now possible to achieve this with CSS [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector.

Simply add the following CSS:

```
body:has(dialog[open]) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you are using [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com):

```
<body className="[&:has(dialog[open])]:overflow-hidden">
```

The above CSS will remove the scrolling from the body when the `dialog` element is open.

Currently every major browser supports the `:has` selector. Check the detailed compatibility [here](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

```css
.long {
  height: 500vh;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

body:has(dialog[open]) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="long">
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').showModal()">open dialog</button>
</div>

<dialog>
  Hello world!
</dialog>
```

Comment: Thanks! I try both Tailwind and CSS, they work very well!

Answer (score 0):

This answer takes the escape key into account. I add a `keydown` event listener to `document.documentElement` rather than the actual `dialog` elements. This is because when a `dialog` has a `keydown` event listener, it doesn't always fire. For example, if a `dialog` is open and a button inside of it has focus and you push the escape key, the `keydown` event listener *will* fire. But let's suppose that the `dialog` has some text in it and you highlight the text and then push the escape key. In this scenario, the `keydown` event listener will *not* fire.

```js
const activeModals = [];

function openModal(dialogSelector) {
  const dialog = document.querySelector(dialogSelector);
  dialog.showModal();
  activeModals.push(dialog);
  document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden');
}

function closeActiveModal() {
  const activeModal = activeModals.pop();
  activeModal.close();

  if (activeModals.length === 0) {
    document.body.classList.remove('overflow-hidden');
  }
}

document.documentElement.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Escape' && activeModals.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    closeActiveModal();
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="modal"]').forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    openModal(button.getAttribute('data-target'));
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('[data-dismiss="modal"]').forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', closeActiveModal);
});

let fillerHtml = '';

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  fillerHtml += `<p>${i}</p>`;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.filler').forEach((div) => {
  div.innerHTML = fillerHtml;
});
```

```css
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog1">Open Dialog 1</button>

<dialog id="dialog1">
  <h1>Dialog 1</h1>
  <button data-dismiss="modal">Close Dialog 1</button>
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog2">Open Dialog 2</button>
  <div class="filler"></div>
</dialog>

<dialog id="dialog2">
  <h1>Dialog 2</h1>
  <button data-dismiss="modal">Close Dialog 2</button>
</dialog>

<div class="filler"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

I created another example where your main content is not scrolled with your modal if it is larger than your main content. You can set `position` to `fixed` on your container to achieve this.

```js
(function() {
  var openBtn = document.getElementById('open-dialog');
  var myDialog = document.getElementById('my-dialog');

  openBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (typeof myDialog.showModal === "function") {
      myDialog.showModal();
    } else {
      alert("Dialog API not supported by browser");
    }
  });

})();
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

#my-dialog {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  top: 3rem;
  width: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#my-dialog__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200vh;
}

menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#cancel-button {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <dialog id="my-dialog">
    <div id="my-dialog__content">
      <form method="dialog">
        <menu>
          <button id="cancel-button" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </menu>
      </form>
    </div>
  </dialog>

  <menu>
    <button id="open-dialog">Open Dialog</button>
  </menu>
</div>
```

**Original answer**

You can set a `max-height` on your dialog and style the contents of your dialog accordingly. See example below.

```js
(function() {
  var openBtn = document.getElementById('open-dialog');
  var myDialog = document.getElementById('my-dialog');

  openBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (typeof myDialog.showModal === "function") {
      myDialog.showModal();
    } else {
      alert("Dialog API not supported by browser");
    }
  });

})();
```

```css
#my-dialog {
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#my-dialog__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150vh;
}

menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#cancel-button {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <dialog id="my-dialog">
    <div id="my-dialog__content">
      <form method="dialog">
        <menu>
          <button id="cancel-button" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </menu>
      </form>
    </div>
  </dialog>

  <menu>
    <button id="open-dialog">Open Dialog</button>
  </menu>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting. What if I want scrolling to work not inside the modal but on the outside i.e. scroll the overlay? You can see the desired effect if you go to https://unsplash.com/photos/bQ-XtB9IWmo?force_page_modal.

Comment: I see. I just updated my answer. Let me know if this is what you were after.

Comment: That works, but it doesn't preserve scrolling of the modal's background when the modal is closed. In my original example, the modal background has a large amount of content, which should be scrollable but only when the modal is closed. Sorry I didn't clarify this in my original post. I'll update my question.

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution is : Once the mnodel is displayed make a one more DIV as overlay which covers full screen, in that place css { pointer-events:none} and model will be placed on top of that. user can not click on body content other than model data.

I have created sample: http://jsfiddle.net/z3sgvnox/

```
<body id="content-body">


<div id="container">
  <dialog id="my-dialog">
    <div id="my-dialog__content">
      <form method="dialog">
        <menu>
          <button id="cancel-button" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </menu>
      </form>
    </div>
  </dialog>

  <menu>
    <button id="open-dialog">Open Dialog</button>
  </menu>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

#my-dialog {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  width: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
      max-height: 80%;
}
.hideScroll{
  overflow:hidden;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#my-dialog__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200vh;
}

menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#cancel-button {
  width: 100%
}
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  var openBtn = document.getElementById('open-dialog');
  var myDialog = document.getElementById('my-dialog');
var bodyData = document.getElementById('content-body');
  openBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (typeof myDialog.showModal === "function") {
      myDialog.showModal();
      bodyData.classList.add("hideScroll");
    } else {
      alert("Dialog API not supported by browser");
    }
  });

})();
```